# Laravel 5.3 and JWT. I'm getting { "error": "token_not_provided" } for all get routes

Tags: angular, authentication, token, jwt, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to implements the authentification using Laravel 5.3 and Angular 2 with JWT.

The Auth part is working and i'm able to get the token, but i'm trying to nagivate to any get routes, i'm getting an error

The code

I have added the provider and aliases, as well as public the vendor folder and generated the key of jwt

In my kernel I have added this:

```
'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
'jwt.refresh' => \TymonJWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
```

and have disabled csrfToken.

These are my routes

```
Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthController', ['only' => ['index']]);
Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthController@authenticate');
Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
```

And my AuthController

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
       // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
       // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
       // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it
       $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Get all roles
        $users = User::with('role', 'branch')->get();

        // Send the response
        return response()->json([
                'users' => $users
            ], 200);
    }

    // Authentification
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        // Retrieve email
        $email              = $request->input('email');

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // Retrieve user
        $user  = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();        

        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
        return response()->json(compact('token'));

        // return response()->json([
        //     'user' => $user,
        //     'token' => compact('token')
        // ], 200);

    }

    // Logout
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required' 
        ]);

        JWTAuth::invalidate($request->input('token'));
    }

}
```

As i said, i could get the token after authentification but when i'm using this token to navigate to some route as this one:

```
Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthController', ['only' => ['index']]);
```

I'm getting this result:

```
{
  "error": "token_not_provided"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypors.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your web server is apache. You need to add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

to your htaccess file in `/path/to/project/public/.htaccess`.

This often the cause of this error . Check this link for more information. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication